# Solve $x^3+3y-xy^\prime=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $x^3+3y-xy^\prime=0$

Divided by $x$ to get $x^2+3\frac{y}{x}-y^\prime=0$

Let $v=\frac{y}{x}$ then $y^\prime=v^\prime x+v$

then $x^2+3v=v^\prime x+v$

then $v^\prime=x+2\frac{v}{x}$

Used integrating factor $e^{\int -2/x dx}=e^{-x^2}$

then $e^{-x^2}v=\int e^{-x^2}\cdot x dx$

But when I solve this $e^{-x^2}v=\frac{-1}{2}e^{-x^2}$

$v=\frac{-1}{2}$

But this isn't the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Divided by $x$ to get $x^2+3\frac{y}{x}-y^\prime=0$

From this step, multiply by negative one to form

$$y'-\frac{3}{x}y=x^2$$

therefore the integrating factor is

$$\mu(x)=\text{exp}\left(-{\int {\frac{3}{x}}dx}\right)=x^{-3}$$

hence the equation can be written as

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right)=\frac{1}{x}$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Integrating factor is not correct....You made a mistake for the integral...
Used integrating factor $e^{∫−2/xdx}=e^{−x^2}$
$$\mu (x)=x^{-2}$$
$$ x^3+3y−xy′=0$$
Multiply by $x^2$
$$ x^3y′-3x^2y=x^5$$
Rewrite as
$$ \frac { x^3y′-3x^2y}{x^6}=\frac 1 x$$
$$\left (\frac { y}{x^3} \right)'=\frac 1 x$$
integrate both sides.